# C++ Template Non-Type Parameter with Parameterized Type

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to have a template parameter, which is not a type, be of a parameterized type, but where those parameters are unknown (i.e. generic)? It's hard to explain with words, but I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

```
template <std::array<int, N> Param>
class Example {
    static size_t length = N;
}
```

This example is clearly contrived, but the idea is that someone could only parameterize this class with a `std::array` value which has `int` element type, but potentially any length. Clearly the code above is not valid C++.

I have found two current ways to achieve this. One is specifying the length of the array as a parameter:

```
template<size_t N, std::array<int, N> Param>
```

Another is to use auto, with some static asserts:

```
template<auto Param>
class Example {
    using T = decltype(Param);
    static_assert(T is std::array type)
    using TValue = T::value_type;
    static_assert(TValue is int)
    static constexpr size_t N = Param.size();
}
```

However the hypothetical example at the top is clearly the cleanest of these. Is there any way to achieve such a template?

This example uses `std::array` but the idea is generic, and this would ideally work for any parameterized types.

Comment: What about using `auto` + `requires`?

Comment: @Evg I was not aware of `requires`. That might be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specialization is another option:

```
template <auto array>
class Example;

template <std::size_t N, std::array<int, N> Param>
class Example<Param> {
    static size_t length = N;
    // ...
};
```